# Access Report Crashes When Clicking Function

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have been experiencing strange behavior with Access 2013 reports.  No matter what computer I run the report on, it crashes every time you click / click and drag on a report text box with a control source set to a function.

The text box is not enabled, and the report doesn't crash if you click any other text boxes, as long as the control source is part of a query.

I am not sure if this is an Access 2013 bug, or I am missing something.  I have tried enabling the text box, and that doesn't solve the problem either.

BTW - this happens on ALL reports, not just one.  I have compacted/repaired the database many times.

Comment: Does it crash if you delete then recreate that textbox?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I just tried.  I removed conditional formatting too, and that didn't help.

Comment: Does the report still crash if you remove the function as the `ControlSource`? If it doesn't crash, what is the code for the function?

Comment: It doesn't crash if you remove it.  In fact, this just got stranger.  In most of my reports the underlying control source is just a datediff.  Some are actual VBA functions, but not all of them crash.  The datediff's always do.  The strange part is that I just remembered, this particular report that I am trying to fix is actually bound to a local temporary table, not to a query.  The code to open the report creates the table first.

Comment: Can you show one of your `Datediff`'s?

Comment: Here is one for example.  This is used in the make table query that creates the table this particular report is bound to.  I used similar datediff's in all the reports, then format the text box to the fixed data type with 1 decimal place.  `code` DIS: DateDiff("d",[inventoryreconditioningstatus]![DateTimeAdded],Now()) `code`

Comment: Also - i noticed that any of the boxes that you can click in and invoke a crash have different behavior when you hover over them with the cursor.  The text boxes that will not cause a crash have no behavior when you mouse over.  The mouse remains a pointer.  When you hover over one of the others that will cause a crash, the pointer turns into the I-beam style cursor, and you can click into the text box.  As I mentioned these are not enabled text boxes, so I don't understand why you can click into them.

Comment: Okay I narrowed down the issue to conditional formatting, but now I need to figure out why.  I have a simple conditional format looking for values greater than 3, and another looking for a specific text string (another box).  When the conditional format is NOT applied, the cursor behaves normally (pointer), and you can click on it without crashing the program.  However when the formatting is applied, the cursor turns to an I beam style, and if you click the text box the report crashes.  Any ideas?